# GLSL: CPU-shared atomic loads

Tags: c++, glsl, atomic, vulkan

I'm working on a C++/Vulkan application that heavily relies on compute shaders. One of these must read (*never write*) buffer memory that might be concurrently modified by the CPU.
Assuming that the CPU and the shader use the appropriate atomic operations, could this work?
To put it in another way, can you safely perform atomic loads of 32/64-bit integers from CPU-shared memory?

(Note: CPU writes to the buffer are expected to be extremely rare)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no mechanism by which plain atomic accesses can simultaneously exist between the host and the GPU. You *have* to use a barrier or event and prevent the host from modifying the memory so long as the GPU is looking at it.

Comment: Oh I forgot to add that even if the CPU has modified the integer in question, it is fine if the GPU reads an outdated value. Is there a way to achieve this behavior?

Comment: @JohnDoe: Undefined behavior is undefined.